# Dismiss custom modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm developing an iPad app where I've created a custom segue to present my view controller with a custom animation. It's now working (almost) fine and in the end it looks like a form modal view controller, exactly how I wanted it to look.

Now I need to create a custom animation for dismissing the modal view controller that matches the first animation.
What is the best way to do it? I have my custom animation inside my custom segue and I think the reverse animation should be there also. But I also think the segue is not the place to have it.

How'd you guys do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use the segue to perform the dismiss of your modal ViewController its jut one way (will change in ios6). just perform your custom dismiss-animation and call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO on the parentViewController in the finished block of the animation.

Comment: I accept your answer although I now believe that creating custom animations for Apple non-fullscreen modal view controllers is not the best approach. I've now moved to create my own container for modal windows so I can animate and customize every element e.g., background overlay, shadow, container, etc. Maybe I'll move the transitions to a Segue but now they're available through a UIViewController category.